# Viewer setThemingColor Promise

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there a possiblity to make setThemingColor async and give a Promise back? Since it itarates over different arrays of objects i should know when the coloring is finished

```js
    await asyncForEach(inputsSameLot, async (input) => {
            // console.log(input);
            var name = '';
            if (input.objectPath.indexOf('/')) {
              name = input.objectPath.split('/')[input.objectPath.split('/').length - 1];
            }
            else {
              name = input.objectPath;
            }
            // // Rot
            // var redColor = new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 1);
            let dbId = this.viewerComponent.viewer.search(name, (idArray) => {
                  this.viewerComponent.viewer.setThemingColor(idArray[0], color);
              // new Promise(resolve);
              // Wenn iterator gleich die Länge ist dass alle Objekte wieder zeigen
              // if (inputsSameLot.length === iterator) {
              //   console.log(inputsSameLot.length + ' ' + iterator);

              // }
              // if (index === 5 && inputsSameLot.length === iterator) {
              //   $('.spinner').hide();
              //   this.viewerComponent.viewer.showAll();
              // }
            }, (err) => {
              this.messageService.add({ key: 'warning', severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Something with COLORING went wrong: ' + err });
            }, ['name']);
          });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Internally, the [setThemingColor](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive) method isn't doing a lot of work - it just iterates over objects under the given *dbid* (if the `recursive` flag is set), it updates the single color value in an internal array, and flags geometries of the *dbid* as "dirty". After the synchronous call to this method returns, you know that all objects have been colored, so there's really no need in waiting for an asynchronous signal that the operation completed.

Comment: I see. But the thing is, that I'm hiding the model, showing the spinner during coloring and therefore I need to know when it is finished. Workaround would be setTimeout, but other solution would be nice.